# PHP: get next n bytes from a text file

Tags: php

I need to iterate over a text file 64 bytes by 64 bytes. I want the next 64 bytes starts just one character after the previous start position! `fread($handle,64)` starts the next bytes from the end of previous bytes.

sth like this:

text file contains:

```
abcdefghi
```

get every 3 bytes:

```
abc
bcd
cde
...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use [`fseek()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fseek.php) to reset the file position indicator before using `fread()`. something like this:

```
for($i=0; $i <= ($filelength-64), $i++){
  fseek($handle, $i);
  $data = fread($handle, 64);
  // process data...
}
```

Comment: Well, if they're using the same file handle, the pointer updates automatically.  No need to seek it.

Comment: @BradKoch: seems like you missunderstood the question - the next `fread()` should _not_ start where the last onehas ended (in wich case you were correct) but instead just one byte after the last _starting_ point.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
for ($line = 0; $line < 64; ++$line)
{
   $str = fread($handle, 64);
   for ($col = 0; $col < 63; col += 3)
   {
      $data = substr($str, $col, 3);
      echo "$data\n";
   }
}
```